# How can I check if a thread is terminated when using pthread?

Tags: pthreads, terminate

I know there is an api called pthread_join, but I don't wanna my thread suspend by any thread.... Any non-blocking method exists?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73468/non-blocking-pthread-join, so depending on your platform you might have pthread_timedjoin available.

Answer (score 0):

There's no POSIX API call, but you could easily implement it yourself, by using a dedicated `bool exited;` variable for each thread, having the thread set it to `true` upon exit and examining it in the other thread, *both* under the protection of a mutex.