# Joining multiple threads without waiting using pthread library and c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Say the main thread created three worker threads.
Suppose all three threads run a function similar to `work()`
 below.

```
bool signal[3]={false};

void* work(void* thread_id)  //each worker thread is given a thread_id when created
{
    int x = *(int*)thread_id;
    int data;
    /*code*/
    signal[x] = true;  //this thread finished
    pthread_exit(&data);
}
```

Usually I use following code to join the threads.

```
int main()
{
    pthread_t workerThreads[3];
    int master;
    /* code for creating threads */
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    { 
        void* status;
        master = pthread_join(workerThreads[i],&status);
        /* code for handling the return data from thread*/
    }  
}
```

What I mean is if `workerThreads[2]` finished before `workerThreads[0]` , with the code above, main thread still have to wait for `workerThreads[0]` finish first before handling `workerThreads[2]`

Is there a way to join the threads without waiting?

Can I use something like this?

```
while(!signal[0]||!signal[1]||!signal[2]){
if(signal[0]){/*join workerThreads[0]*/}
if(signal[1]){/*join workerThreads[1]*/}
if(signal[2]){/*join workerThreads[2]*/}
}
```

Comment: If your goal is to join *all* the threads anyway, why does matter that you're waiting for one longer than another?

Comment: Joining *is* waiting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-blocking pthread\_join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73468/non-blocking-pthread-join)

Comment: Do you want to wait only until **one**  of the threads finishes(the first that finishes), or do you still want to wait until **all** threads are finished ?