# Joining POSIX threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix

I have the following situation:

In my C code under Linux I start a number threads in sequence with phtread_create(). Once this is done I invoke pthread_join() in a loop for all of the threads above, in the order in which they were created. Since I don't know when a given thread is going to terminate and join, it might be the case that my code is blocked waiting for the first thread to join, while some of the other threads that were created later have already terminated and are waiting to join.

What I am looking for is something that behaves like pthread_join(), but with the peculiarity that it would stop blocking whenever ANY of the threads created above terminates. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-blocking pthread\_join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73468/non-blocking-pthread-join)

Comment: Thanks. While not exactly what I had in mind it does provide the basic capability to do what I want.

Comment: I don't think the linked question is a duplicate _per se_.  What that question seeks to do (a non-blocking join), and what this one asks to do (block until the any one of _N_ threads terminate) are rather different.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the same effect by not using `pthread_join` but instead your own synchronization construct.  (For what it's worth, POSIX.1-2017 explicitly regards `pthread_join` [as a convenience](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html#tag_16_432_08), not as a multithreading primitive.)

If you don't need your worker threads' return values, you can simply have a shared counter — protected by a mutex and accompanied by a condition variable — that each (detached) thread decrements and signals when it is "done."  Effectively, this is Java's [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

If you do want to collect their return values, have each (detached) worker put its value to a thread-safe queue.

Since you're no longer relying on `join`, you can run the worker threads as detached.

In either scenario, your waiting thread can do whatever it likes after any decrement or dequeuing.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you want to use a function like [`pthread_tryjoin_np`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_tryjoin_np.3.html) or `pthread_timedjoin_np`:

> The pthread_tryjoin_np() function performs a nonblocking join
> with the thread thread, returning the exit status of the thread
> in *retval.  If thread has not yet terminated, then instead of
> blocking, as is done by pthread_join(3), the call returns an
> error.

It's non-standard though, so your milage may vary.